# I am using react native . my app stops on fast scrolling, and xcode shows "thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=1 address=0x18)"

Tags: react-native, xcode8

whenever I scroll too fast in my  it loads properly, but after some time the app stops responding and xcode shows the following error :

```
"thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=1 address=0x18)" .
```

How can I resolve it ?

Comment: I think its out of memory issue..

Comment: how can I resolve it? @Jickson

Comment: Please post code which is creating issue